# Java varhandle/ memory modes

Tags: java, concurrency

I understood the theory behind varhandles and the different memory modes, but finding it hard to write examples/ small programs that demonstrate how different modes behave.

Are you aware of any documentation, public git repos or other resources that might help in this?

Comment: You might have been confused due to hardware memory model acting to strengthen the JVM's, as you only specify the weakest allowed but the compiler or hardware may still perform stronger instructions. As x86 is total-store-order (TSO), that can mask bugs that weaker models like ARM's can expose. This makes it hard to show the differences between modes like plain vs opaque in practice, even though they have important distinctions for theoretical correctness.

Comment: @BenManes Agree with you on the lack of processor issues, but was still expecting some compiler issues to surface. Will try some code examples on an ARM processor and see how it goes.

Comment: A nice [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EFkpmFt61Jo) where the developer did not understand the hardware, tried to be smart, and was surprised when their code failed on ARM. They assumed a failed CAS created a memory barrier because of TSO and blamed the docs for their ignorance. Interestingly it is hard to find the JVM using weaker modes as experts make mistakes too (e.g. I rediscovered this [bug](https://markmail.org/message/yvnrcy6jx777rdhr) when investigating an [issue](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/issues/77)). I have not observed cost diff between weaker modes; just risk

Comment: Thanks for your insight ! Really interesting example, didn't know that about CAS. I managed to get some failures on an ARM processor (Trying out some things on a Graviton instance) - will try to document these scenarios :)

Comment: If you get neat insights then please share them with me too :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of amazing writings from Aleksey Shipilëv ([https://shipilev.net](https://shipilev.net/)) regarding the Java memory model:

- [Close Encounters of The Java Memory Model Kind](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/close-encounters-of-jmm-kind/)
- [Java Memory Model Pragmatics (transcript)](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/jmm-pragmatics/)

Also I can recommend taking a look at [jcstress](https://github.com/openjdk/jcstress) (Java Concurrency Stress) library for experimenting with Java Concurrency. A good start would be the examples in the same git [repository](https://github.com/openjdk/jcstress/tree/master/jcstress-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jcstress/samples).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).